# using `lpr` to get file name and page numbers printed on pdf

Tags: solaris, printing, pdf

I have a PDF file and I want to print it with the file name and page numbers added somewhere on the page. Is this possible with `lpr`? If not, what utility can I use to transform the PDF file first? I'm on Solaris 10.

Comment: There are several implementations of lpr with different options. Which one do you have: old-style BSD lpr, lprNG, or CUPS? What distribution are you using? Are you printing text files, PDF files, something else?

Comment: @Gilles I am printing pdf files. The version of `lpr` is that included with `SunOS 5.10`. (I cannot find specific version information).

I am beginning to believe this is something that will require a solution outside of `lpr`. (say with postscript).

Comment: I doubt that any lp/lpr implementation can add headers to a PDF file. Typical implementations only have capabilities to add headers while converting text to the printer format. Does Solaris 10 even have any support for PDF?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, `lpr` is able to print PDFs on this Solaris machine.

Comment: @Gilles Would you by chance know how to do this with postscript? I can use `acroread` to convert PDF to PS.

Answer (score 2):

`lpr` has a pretty-printing option: `-p`.

From the man page:

> -p
>   Specifies that the print file should be formatted with a shaded header with the date, time, job  name,  and  page  number.
>   This option is equivalent to "-o prettyprint" and is only useful when printing text files.

This option will work only with ASCII files (so, no `ps` files for example). It doesn't depend on the device so it will work if you print to pdf the same way it would if you print with a real printer.

Comment: I'm familiar with `-p` but I am printing PDF files. Is there a way I can do this with PDFs?

Comment: Ok. I've understood that you intended to use a PDF printer. My mistake. In that case, `lpr` indeed is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think [mpage](http://www.mesa.nl/pub/mpage/) will work for this.  Use `-1` single page mode and `-H` header which will include the page number.   Obviously you will have to play around with this until you get what you desire.